# Blacklist or purge brcmfmac on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: drivers, broadcom, purge, blacklist

I need to either blacklist or purge the broadcom driver brcmfmac in order to  disable a broadcom wifi/bluetooth adapter in my system. Can anybody explain to me how to do it?

The reason is I'm running a dual boot system and I need to use the broadcom wifi/BT card on my other boot (hackintosh) and the integrated wifi/BT intel chip with the Ubuntu boot.

Currently Ubuntu sees both cards and occasionally there are several conflicts. As a test,I removed the intel chip and used the broadcom card on both OS's but this performed very bad with Linux while the Intel one performs very well.

On the MacOS boot (where the Intel chip is not compatible) I was able to disable the Intel chip and now I need to disable the broadcom wifi/BT card in Ubuntu. I thought that I should be able to achieve this by blacklisting or removing the driver?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the procedure might have changed in 19.04 but generally speaking:

1) you need to find the driver / kernel module that is using your device

2) you need to blacklist it in `/etc/modprobe.d/` writing a file with the content `blacklist yourkernelmodule`

---

**An Example:**

type `ls -knn`

The output is a huge list. Identify your device. In my case `Ethernet controller` for example

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Onboard Ethernet [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

The kernel driver / module is r8169.

If I would like to blacklist that driver:

`echo blacklist r8169 > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-r8169.conf`

Now the driver should no longer be automatically loaded on boot.

To remove the already loaded driver type:
`rmmod r8169` and / or `modprobe -r r8169`

---

To unblock that driver again the file needs to be removed

`rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-r8169.conf`

Comment: That worked for the Wifi part of the card, thank you. Then I figured out that the Bluetooth was still operational so I had to disable the Bluetooth part by creating a udev rule.

Comment: i expect your bluetooth device beeing loaded by a module either.